# Intersection of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $\mathfrak{a}$, $\mathfrak{b}$ be ideals in $A$.

I am asked the following question:

Show that $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ is the largest ideal of $A$ contained in the ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}.$

Proof:

Let $x \in \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ $\implies x \in \mathfrak{a}$ and $x \in \mathfrak{b}$ and let $r \in A$.  Then $x \in \mathfrak{a}$ and also $rx \in \mathfrak{a}$ since $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal.  Since $x \in \mathfrak{b}$, we also have that $rx \in \mathfrak{b}$ since $\mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal.  This implies that $rx \in \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$.

So I have showed that $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ is an ideal, but how do I show that $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ is the largest ideal contained in both $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: In your last lines it must be the intersection is the largest ideal CONTAINED in both $\;\mathfrak a\,,\,\mathfrak b\;$ , not containing them.

Comment: To show the intersection is an ideal, we also need to show that it is an additive subgroup of the additive group of the ring. Closed under multiplication by ring elements is not enough.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thats right.  I only did half of the work.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\;I\;$ be an ideal contained in both $\;\mathfrak a\,,\mathfrak b\;$ . Then it is also contained in their intersection $\;\mathfrak a\cap\mathfrak b\;$ , and this proves the maximality.